# Run UiAutomator API from Android Studio (v0.8)

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-uiautomator

When I work with tests - I add class in special module and run test configuration. Class extend (for example) TestCase and work well.

But when I extend UiAutomatorTestCase - I get error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase.<init>  (UiAutomatorTestCase.java:5) ...
```

My simple class:

```
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException;
import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;

public class AutoTest extends UiAutomatorTestCase {
    public void testSome() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
        getUiDevice().pressHome();
    }
}
```

How to run it in Android Studio IDE?

Comment: I wonder why no one has answered this one...did you get it figured out?

Comment: @TimBo no, I don't =( Use only simple TestCase...

Comment: I tried with this and it;s working great..http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you'd be interested in giving it another try....I was able to get a UIAutomator project started in Android Studio with the following [Github project] (https://github.com/wiliamsouza/bluetooth)

1. Clone the project locally.
2. Edit the gradle.properties file to point to your sdk, target and build tools
3. Import into Android Studio, if prompted be sure to select Gradle.

The accompanying [blog post] (http://wiliamsouza.github.io/#/2013/10/30/android-uiautomator-gradle-build-system) has more details.

I modified with my own test cases and is working well.

Comment: How to bundle 3rd library when gradle build dex jar file ?

Comment: Ahhh yes....I haven't found an answer to that yet....I have an SO question for that myself